# How to automatically generate sequent numbers when using a form

Tags: forms, numbers, google-sheets, sequence, auto-generate

Ahab stated in 2010: the complex looking number based on the Timestamp has one important property, the number can not change when rows are deleted or inserted.
As long as the submitted data is not changed by inserting deleting rows the simple formula `=ArrayFormula(ROW(A2:A) - 1)` may be the easiest one to use.

For other situations there is no nice reliable solution. :(

Now we live in 2015. Maybe times have changed?

I need a reliable way to number entries using a form.

Maybe a script can do the trick? A script that can add 1 to each entry?
That certain entry has to keep that number even when rows are deleted or inserted.

I created this simple spreadsheet in which I added 1,2, and 3 manually,please have a look:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H9EXns8-7m9oLbCrTyIZhLKXk6TGxzWlO9pOvQSODYs/edit?usp=sharing

The script has to find the maximum of the former entries, which is 3, and then add 1 automatically.

Who can help me with this?

Grtz, Bij

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe a script can do the trick? A script that can add 1 to each
>   entry?

Yes, that would be what you need to resort to. I took the liberty of entering this in your example ss:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var watchColumns = [1, 2]; //when text is entered in any of these columns, auto-numbering will be triggered
  var autoColumn = 3;
  var headerRows = 1;
  var watchSheet = "Form";

  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (e.value !== undefined && sheet.getName() == watchSheet) {
    if (watchColumns.indexOf(range.getColumn()) > -1) {
      var row = range.getRow();
      if (row > headerRows) {
        var autoCell = sheet.getRange(row, autoColumn);
        if (!autoCell.getValue()) {
          var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
          var temp = 1;
          for (var i = headerRows, length = data.length; i < length; i++)
            if (data[i][autoColumn - 1] > temp)
              temp = data[i][autoColumn - 1];
          autoCell.setValue(temp + 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for contributing. I can't make your script running, it says: TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 7, file ""). I am a complete zero in scripting, maybe you can fix it?

Comment: Bij, the idea is that this script should run automatically when you make an edit in the spreadsheet. Running it from the Script Editor, for example, will generate the error you described.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way is to create a query in a second sheet pulling everything from form responses in to second column and so on. then use the first column for numbering.

In your second sheet **B1** you would use:

```
=QUERY(Form!1:1004)
```

In your second sheet **A2** you would use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B="",,Row(B2:B)-1))
```

I made a second sheet in your example spreadsheet, have a look at it.